# Explain the difference between type 1,2,3,4 sums of squares

Tags: sums-of-squares

Can someone explain the difference between type 1:4 sums of squares using examples with relatable variables?

Comment: Perhaps a link:  http://mcfromnz.wordpress.com/2011/03/02/anova-type-iiiiii-ss-explained/

Comment: @Drew75 The blog is just copying and pasting the proper information here: http://goanna.cs.rmit.edu.au/~fscholer/anova.php
While that info. helps it doesn't directly address the explanation with examples part of my question.

Comment: I'm accumulating downvotes for this question. Can someone explain why or suggest a change to the wording? Should I remove it? Does it not belong in stats.stackexchange.com?